# What is the interval of this CRON expression?

Tags: java, cron

I am unable to decode the interval defined in the CRON expression below,
Please explain it with some details.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * 1/1 * ?")
```

I understand the basic structure of a CRON sequence but I can't find what does `0/1` or `1/1` means?

Comment: thanks but i am still unable to understand what does **0/1** means ?

Comment: I found this: https://cronexpressiondescriptor.azurewebsites.net/
here i am able to see what the **/** means, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a cron expression, the various fields have a strict range which values are allowed:

```
field          allowed values
-----          --------------
minute         0-59
hour           0-23
day of month   1-31
month          1-12 (or names, see below)
day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sunday, or use names)
```

A field may contain an <asterisk> (`*`), which always stands for `<first>-<last>`.  Another possibility is *ranges of numbers*.  Ranges are two numbers separated with a <hyphen> (`-`).  The specified range is inclusive.  For example, `8-11` matches all number `8,9,10,11`

In combination with ranges, you can have a *step value*, noted as `/<number>` which tells you how many numbers should be skipped in the range. Example: `2-7/2` allows the numbers `2,4,6`.

In some cron-systems, the notation `<start>/<number>` is a shorthand for `<start>-<last>/<number>`. Such an example is the Quartz Job Scheduling Library:

> The `/` character can be used to specify increments to values. For example, if you put `0/15` in the Minutes field, it means *every 15th minute of the hour, starting at minute zero*. If you used `3/20` in the Minutes field, it would mean *every 20th minute of the hour, starting at minute three* – or in other words it is the same as specifying `3,23,43` in the Minutes field. Note the subtlety that `/35` does *not mean `every 35 minutes` - it means *every 35th minute of the hour, starting at minute zero* – or in other words the same as specifying `0,35`.
>
> **<sub>source: [Quartz Job Scheduling Library Manual](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06.html)</sub>**